# Icons in the floating action button on react native not shows the text if the position is center

Tags: react-native

If I set the position as 'center' in the react-native-floating-actions, it not showing the text which I have added in actions.

Only showing the icons background as circle

[image]

https://snack.expo.io/@niph/b8123e

Comment: Question is not clear. can you add the image and more details?

Comment: Edited the above.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [configuration](https://github.com/santomegonzalo/react-native-floating-action#configuration) before the implementation. Here the author mentioned, Text won't be shown when it is aligned "center". Kindly go through the docs. If you want to override this, just modify and give PR to the author.

Comment: But there is no option to add bottom values. (i.e) i need to add bottom value to move the icon above the screen. Styles are not reflecting any changes in my UI